# Artisan change column comments with name in dash

Tags: php, laravel-5, artisan-migrate

I want to change a columns comment in MySQL table with Laravel.

However, I get an error when migrating.

> ```
> "Syntax error (SQL: ALTER TABLE category CHANGE zh-TW zh-TW VARCHAR(191) 
> NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name in Chinese')".
> ```

Code as follow:

```
Schema::table('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('zh-TW')->comment('Name in Chinese')->change();
});
```

Comment: Try to backtick it `'\`zh-TW\`'`

Comment: Thank you, but not work as below
$table->string('`zh-TW`')->comment('Name in Chinese')->change();

Comment: I'd expect Laravel to add the backticks for you, but since it isn't... have you tried adding them yourself, using `\DB::raw()`? ie: ``$table->string(\DB::raw("`zh-TW`"))->comment('Name in Chinese')->change();``

Comment: Thanks for @chiliNUT . But still not work too. I use below code to solve this issue
`DB::statement("ALTER TABLE category CHANGE \`zh-TW\` \`zh-TW\` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL comment 'Name in Chinese';");`
It is wired, because I can use `$table->string('zh-TW');` to create column, but can not change in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use code as below

```
`DB::statement("ALTER TABLE category CHANGE `zh-TW` `zh-TW` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL comment 'Name in Chinese';");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use DB statement

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE category CHANGE zh-TW zh-TW VARCHAR(191) 
NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name in Chinese'");
}
```